# jdbi throws SQLException: Unknown system variable 'tx_read_only'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jdbi

This happens pretty with all queries but the stacktrace I'm looking at creates it at handle.update() with some simple query.

Everything works just fine on the laptop I'm developing with but fails miserably on the server.

```
Laptop:
OS: Ubuntu 15.10
jdbi: 2.73
java: Oracle 1.8.0_91 
mysql: 14.14 Distrib 5.6.30, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Server:
OS: Linux Mint 17.1
jdbi: 2.73
java: Oracle 1.8.0_91-b14
mysql: 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49 for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

As far as my understanding goes, the databases have been initalized the same way.

JDBC connectors should also be identical as I'm using the very same Gradle file to build in both environments.

Comment: [tx_read_only](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tx_read_only) was introduced in 5.6.5, which means it does not exist on your server.

Comment: Can you upgrade your remote MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to 5.7 did the trick, as @joachim-isaksson suggested. Thought that 14.14 was the version and the distribution part just some somewhat meaningless string.